# Why does Rembrandt keep calling Quinn "Q-ball"?

Tags: sliders

In "Sliders," Rembrandt keeps calling Quinn "Q-ball". Why does he do that?

I think I know, I would just like to make sure. In theoretical physics, [Q-ball refers to a type of non-topological soliton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-ball). The physics in ***Sliders*** is kind of hairy: not exactly far-fetched, just silly, like no one's even trying to pursue ... well, *any* level of scientific verisimilitude. I was thinking that one of the authors may have misread "soliton" as "solution" and figured he'd impress the hell out of his/her colleagues with his/her superior knowledge.

Comment: Other than just a cool nickname starting in Q? Well, Wikipedia [claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quinn_Mallory) it's because of "his role as instigator of their adventures" [i.e. he got the ball rolling], but I'm not sure what they're basing this on.

Comment: @Walt: Thank you. Could you copy and paste it to the answer space so I could upvote it and mark the green tick thingie next to it?

Comment: Well, you might want to wait for someone a bit more knowledgable... ;) I barely remember the series. BTW, don't be afraid to add your own theory and thoughts about the name to the question, it'll flesh it out a bit.

Comment: @Walt: Done....

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Done.

Comment: @Ricky Interesting. But would Rembrandt really know this?

Comment: @Walt: No, no one who's not into physics would. Which is why the writer who looked up the term convinced everybody that Rembrandt calls Quinn "Q-ball" because he's the instigator of adventures and all. Then, ten episodes into the first season, he revealed his secret, earning the right to look down on the rest of the team as a bunch of ignorant morons. Just a theory.

Comment: I watched most of this series and I always just assumed it was a nickname derived from the first letter of his name and the fact that he was white.

Comment: @sanpaco I thought the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be a hangover from an [earlier version of the script](http://earthprime.com/content/sliders-scripts-collection/sliders-1994-03-11.pdf). The alternate Quinn they meet attempts to explain the differences between the various parallel realities using a roulette metaphor with themselves as the ball/s.

> **ARTURO:** *Your double said Sliding was like spinning a roulette wheel. Our "ball" must've landed on an Earth that's suffered a
>   terrible climactic cataclysm.*
>
> [shortly afterwards]
>
> **REMBRANDT:** *End of discussion Q-ball. We're OUTTA here!*

In the [revised show script](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=sliders&episode=s01e01), the conversations are much farther apart, making the connection less clear.

Obviously the nickname suits quite nicely since he's white (e.g. [cue ball](http://snapjudgment.org/sites/default/files/cueball-sm.jpg))

Comment: Apropos of nothing, in the earliest version of the script, he just called him "*man*"... **REMBRANDT:** *Who cares what did it, man! The question is, how we gettin' home?!*